# How can I move all customers to a different Website in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, customer

I migrated all customer data to my new Magento2 store, but a new Website and Store View was created. I have already built out all of my products, design, etc on an original Website/Store View.

I know I can update accounts individually, but is there a way to move all of these customer accounts to the correct Website and Store View in bulk?

Ideally, I would like to avoid sending any "welcome" notifications when this is done.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way I can think of is modifying `customer_entity` table.

Let's define two variables, `OLD_WEBSITE_ID` and `NEW_WEBSITE_ID`. Then you can run the following sql query. You will change with actual IDs where you see `OLD_WEBSITE_ID` and `NEW_WEBSITE_ID`.

```
UPDATE `customer_eav_attribute_website` SET `website_id` = NEW_WEBSITE_ID WHERE `website_id` = OLD_WEBSITE_ID;
```

After running this SQL query, you should also run `bin/magento indexer:reindex` command to re-create indexes.

Please **back-up** your database. Executing raw MySQL queries is dangerous!

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Just updated the customer_entity table.